# Minipage positioning problem

Tags: minipage

I want to divide my page into 9 cells(3x3) and each cell contains one minipage. So, I set the minpage width as `0.33\textwidth`. Problem is minipage of cell (2,3) moved to (3,1).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\\

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try this:` ...\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}...` without a new line or space between and and next beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an empty line between minipages (2,2) and (2,3), which makes a new paragraph.
Just delete this empty line. It is the line 40 in your example.

Here is my MWE. Note I have changed font in the line 9, because I don't have Linux Biolinum font installed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Ani}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\\

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\linewidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]